# Regular expression result

Tags: python, regex

I have below code:

```
import re

line = "78349999234";

searchObj = re.search(r'9*', line)

if searchObj:
   print "searchObj.group() : ", searchObj.group()
else:
   print "Nothing found!!"
```

However the output is empty. I thought `*` means: Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. `ab*` will match `‘a’`, `‘ab’`, or `‘a’` followed by any number of `‘b’`s. Why am I not able to see any result in this case?

Comment: Why have you pasted a screenshot of your question into your question? That has nothing to do with this question. If you have a question about StackOverflow, post it on [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), not in the middle of an unrelated question here.

Answer (score 5):

I think the regular expression matches *left to right*. So the first pattern that matches is the empty string before `7...`. If it find a `9`, it will indeed match it greedy: and try to "*eat*" (that's the correct terminology) as many characters as possible.

If you query for:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r'9*',line));
['', '', '', '', '9999', '', '', '', '']
```

It matches all empty strings between the characters and as you can see, `9999` is matched as well.

The main reason is probably performance: if you search for a pattern in a string of 10M+ characters, you're very happy if the pattern is already in the first 10k characters. You don't want to waste effort on finding the "*nicest*" match...

---

**EDIT**

With *0 or more occurrence* one means the group (in this case `9`) is repeated zero or more times. In an empty string, the characters is repeated exactly 0 times. If you want to match patterns where the characters is repeated **one or more times**, you should use

```
9+
```

This results in:

```
>>> print(re.search(r'9+', line));
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 8), match='9999'>
```

`re.search` for a pattern that accepts the empty string, is probably not that much helpful since it will always match the empty string **before** the actual start of the string first.

Comment: Thanks, What is meant by 0 or more occurrence? And I am not able ot see the cide in stackoverflow these days. It appears blur. Any reason for that?

Comment: The answer doesn't explain the fix the OP probably wants: `9+` instead of `9*`.

Comment: @user3369157: what do you mean with the "cide", is this a typo for "side"?

Comment: Did you override the style sheet in your browser by any chance? Perhaps you can select the code and the it "*inverts*" colors...

Comment: It appearsas shown in the ic which i just added. I am not able to view what I am typing also.

Comment: @user3369157: This is rather strange, never seen anything like this on SO. What happens if you use another browser (Firefox, Chrome,...)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is , `re.search` function stops searching for strings once it finds a match. `9*` means match the digit 9 **zero** or more times. Because an empty string exists before each and every character, `re.search` function stops it searching after finding the first empty string. That's why you got an empty string as output...